# go through string laravel and get values

Tags: php, json, laravel

I have string like this:

```
 $filters= {"DestinationZone":"","date":"2019-12-13","PolicyName":"","CloseReason":"","ApplicationName":"","level":"","Host":""}
```

I want to go through this string and divide it   to key and value
I tried a lot but I don't know why it does not want to work.
this is the code which I tried

```
   $filters=str_replace('{','', $filters);
  $filters=str_replace('}','', $filters);
 $filters=explode(',',$filters);    
  for($i=0;$i<count($filters);$i++){
$xx=explode(':',$filters[$i]);
var_dump($xx);
foreach ($xx as $xx) 
{  $value=trim($xx,'"');
var_dump($value);
 // $key=trim($key,'"');

if (!empty($value)) {

 //$query->where("$key", '=', "$value");
}
 }

  }
```

I think this code is very mess , I am using laravel

Comment: just use `json_decode($filters, true)`, and you will get the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not about Laravel frameworks, but just basic PHP.

---

#### Variable

You have an error with the `$filters` variable.

```php
$filters= {"DestinationZone":"","date":"2019-12-13","PolicyName":"","CloseReason":"","ApplicationName":"","level":"","Host":""}
```

The JSON you have must be a string.

```php
$filters = '{"DestinationZone":"","date":"2019-12-13","PolicyName":"","CloseReason":"","ApplicationName":"","level":"","Host":""}';
```

---

#### Key - Value

If you want to convert `$filters` to an array, you can just use :

```php
$filters = json_decode($filters, true);
```

**Result**

```
array:7 [
  "DestinationZone" => ""
  "date" => "2019-12-13"
  "PolicyName" => ""
  "CloseReason" => ""
  "ApplicationName" => ""
  "level" => ""
  "Host" => ""
]
```